# API with info on credit card offers

Tags: database, api

Does anyone know of any API that contains up-to-date information on credit cards being offered my major companies? Looking to provide a consolidated list of offerings as part of a product making recommendations to people looking to get a card, but so far every Google search has turned up APIs that process and/or verify credit card payments.

Does anyone know if this exists? Or is it something where the data would have to be manually added?

Comment: Did you get answer for this question yet? I have an answer, let me know if you want me to write it down here!! Good luck with your search.

Comment: Hey @sandeep, I'd love to see your answer if you're willing to share!